# No puedo agregar widgets con el diseñador en Xamarin Studio 6.1

Tags: xamarin

Recientemente actualicé a Xamarin studio 6.1 y desde entonces no puedo agregar controles de forma visual en el diseñador. Solo puedo hacerlo mediante código XML. Antes de actualizar funcionaba bien. Si a alguien mas le ha pasado... ¿cómo lo solucionó? Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías agregar también la información sobre la versión de Visual Studio que estás usando

Comment: Te recomiendo usar Xamarin en Visual Studio.